# Cannot resolve constructor Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

- Im trying to add a tabhost to my application but i cant figure why this error 'cannot resolve constructor intent' is showing, here's my activity code:

  ```
  public class SixthFragment extends Fragment {
  public static final String TAG = "sixth";



  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,       Bundle   savedInstanceState) {

  View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.sixthfragment, container, false);
  TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) view.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

  TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
  TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
  TabHost.TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third tab");

  // Set the Tab name and Activity
  // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected
  tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
  tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));

  tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
  tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

  tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
  tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));

  /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
  tabHost.addTab(tab1);
  tabHost.addTab(tab2);
  tabHost.addTab(tab3);


  return view;


  }


  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

  }



  }
  ```

  some help would be apreciated, thanks for your time.

Comment: use `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to the `Intent` constructor that you are trying to use takes a `Context`. `Fragment` is not a `Context`. Use `getActivity()` instead of `this`.